# Convert typdef into template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, overloading, undefined-symbol

I have an overloaded function which accepts two different types of parameter (factorywv) as below. I am working under Solaris environment.

```
typedef AISObject *(*factorywv)();
namespace bcMwMrsh
{
 template<typename listT>
 void cppListFromWire(void *&src,RWTValSlist<listT> &dest, factorywv);
} 

int FormAccountSetupList::fromWire(void *&buf, long bufLen)
{
        bcMwMrsh::cppListFromWire(buf, contents, FormAccountSetupRow::AISFactory);
        return 0;
}
```

AISFactory and contents are defined as below,

```
static AISObject *AISFactory() { return new FormAccountSetupList; }
RWTValSlist<FormAccountSetupRow *> contents;
```

These two functions are called in different cpp files.
Currently I am facing the below error and understood function template may solve the problem.

```
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
void bcMwMrsh::cppListFromWire<FormATMSetupRow*>(void*&, RWTValSlist<FormATMSetupRow*, std::allocator<FormATMSetupRow*> >&, AISObject* (*)()) actsetup.o
```

Could some one please let me know how can I convert the typdefs to templatized form? Or my understanding of the problem is correct?

Comment: [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: I don't see how this has anything to do with `typedef`.

Comment: You simply need to provide a definition for your `cppListFromWire` function.

Comment: Definition already exists but the point how to link it in the runtime

Comment: [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) Where exactly does the definition of `cppListFromWire` exist?

Comment: It does exists 2 places as below, it was initialy defined in cpp files which I commented to be defined in .h files.  wv/include/cppmarsh.h
  and one more under bc/include/bcMwMrsh.h. Both has different implementations. template<typename listT>
void cppListFromWire(void *&src,RWTValSlist<listT> &list, factorywv factoryFunc)